# Environment variables don't last after being set (in a container)

Tags: python-3.x, docker, environment-variables

I don't know if being inside a docker container has any relation with the problem but for the record I am running all inside a container.

I tried running this script

```
import os

os.environ['A_VAR']='aValue'
thevalue=os.environ.get('A_VAR',None)
print(thevalue)
```

with this I set the environment `A_VAR` to some value and I can see it from the print that is set

then I run the following

```
import os
'
thevalue=os.environ.get('A_VAR',None)
print(thevalue)
```

and no, the value is not set.

Running ``printenv` also shows that the values is not set.

Why is setting the environment variable not working and how it should be done?

Answer (score 2):

Environment variables are local the the process setting it and all processes spawned from it (they inherit the environment). So you can set the environment for the child processes, but not for the parent.

Your python script runs as its own process so any changes it made to the environment disappear when this process exits.

Comment: So, is there any way to set the environment variables through a script with changes that last? or is it not possible?

Comment: It would only be possible if it happens in the same process, for example a shell script that is sourced rather than executed.

Comment: I see. So a shell script is needed, and python cannot be used...